Remove div inside parent div in jquery object only
I have a divs inside parent div:
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">some content1</div>
  <div id="child">some content1</div>
</div> 

I get the parent div using jQuery:
var allDivs= $("#parent").html();

I want to remove child divs from this parent, how I can do this? Child divs should be deleted from jQuery object but not from DOM, is it possible?

Element ids should be unique.

Are you looking to use them elsewhere in the DOM? or simply hide them?

allDivs contains a string, not "the parent div" or any other DOM element...

The jQuery object is just a wrapper around an actual DOM element. If you want to remove child elements from an element, they will be removed from the DOM.

Can you explain what the purpose is of this? What do you plan to do afterwards?

@Mr.Polywhirl I only want to remove from jquery object not from DOM. Later i am exporting html to csv or excel.

So my understanding of jquery html() is that it would only retrieve the child elements of #parent; removing them would leave allDivs empty. My question, then, is What's the point of retrieving them just to remove them and leave nothing in the variable? Are you using or manipulating them first? Are there other child elements of #parent?

Yes there are other child of parents, i want to delete only one div but there are others many.

@Mushi: "i want to delete only one div but there are others" - Yet in the question you wrote: "I want to remove child divs from this parent" - And in the code shown all of the child elements of the parent are "child" elements.  Please clarify what you're asking, and include a [mcve] which clearly demonstrates what you are attempting, and indicate specifically what isn't working as expected in that example.

Which div(s) do you want to delete? Does it have to be in jquery? What about something like allDivs = document.querySelectorAll("#parent *"); then you could iterate through them and delete as desired.

Or if you want everything except the first child div, document.querySelectorAll("#parent *:not(:first-child)")


some content1
some content1
 i want output like this: 
some content1
 means remove a child, but it should not be deleted from DOM
@Mushi: Please edit the question to indicate specifically what logic you are trying to implement.  "I want output like this" does not describe that logic.  In the current form of the question you indicate that all child element should be removed.  In a previous comment you indicate that some should be removed.  In that last comment you indicate that one should be removed. For the "some" or "one" cases you don't indicate how you would determine which element(s) should be removed. Please take some time and describe the problem for which you have been given multiple solutions.

@David, Thanks i will do that.


child divs should be deleted from jquery object but not from dom

Deleting them from the jQuery object which references the DOM would remove them from the DOM.  However, you can clone that object and then modify the clone all you like.
For example:


var allDivs = $("#parent").html();
console.log("all divs: ", allDivs);

var parentDiv = $("#parent").clone().empty().html();
console.log("only parent: ", parentDiv);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child">some content1</div>
  <div class="child">some content1</div>
</div>



As you can see in the second operation above, after selecting the "parent" you can call .clone() to create an in-memory clone of the structure, then .empty() to remove all child elements from that (in-memory) parent element.

Edit: If you want to remove only some child elements then instead of .empty() you'd want to specifically target and remove those elements.  For example:


var allDivs = $("#parent").html();
console.log("all divs: ", allDivs);

var someDivs = $("#parent").clone();
someDivs.find(".child").remove();
console.log("some divs: ", someDivs.html().trim());
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child">some content1</div>
  <div class="child">some content1</div>
  <div class="keep">some content1</div>
  <div class="keep">some content1</div>
</div>




how i can remove child div from parentDiv using jquery?

@Mushi: Is the answer above not working for you in some way?  Please clarify the problem.

Cloning the DOM, without modifying, makes the most sense here.

.empty method should do the trick for you...
allDivs.empty()


If you tested this you'd observe an error: "Uncaught TypeError: allDivs.empty is not a function" - In the code shown in the question, allDivs is a string.

i didnt see the .html() so you should remove that method.

Doing that would remove the elements from the DOM, which the question explicitly indicates is not desired.
